# Less space than MainAxisSize.min between Column's children in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have read some discussions around having more spacing between children in a Column, however I would like to make them more close to each other.
I would like to have the 2 text like this:

[image]

My code for now, which makes the 'Days' text too far apart from the number:

```
Widget numberOfDays = Container(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
     Text(
        '$_counter', // 25
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4,
      ),
     Text(
        'Days',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Maybe it's not possible with a column? Should I use stack maybe and position them accordingly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      '25', // 25
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4,
    ),
    Positioned(
      right: 0,
      bottom: 10,
      child: Text(
        'Days',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: 'Hey, that's pretty good!' Thank you kindly, it worked like a charm:)